# Dominated convergence theorem to show $F$ is integrable.

Tags: integration, derivatives, lebesgue-integral

$(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mu)$ measure space. We have a map $f : \Omega \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ with these three properties:

a) For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ :  $f(x,\star) : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is integrable.

b) For all $\omega \in \Omega$: $f(\star, \omega) : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable.

c) There exists an integrable function $g$, so that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ : $|\frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x, \star) | \le g$ $\mu$-almost everywhere.

Show that:

$F: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  is differentiable.

$$F(x) := \int_{\Omega} f(x,\omega) d\mu(\omega).$$

And show that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$:

$$F '(x) = \int_{\Omega} \frac{\partial}{\partial x} f(x,\omega) d\mu(\omega)$$

So what I have tried:

I'm pretty sure, that we have to use the dominated convergence theorem for Lebesgue integration. First of all we could start with $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_o} \frac{F(x)-F(x_o)}{x-x_o}$. Then we get $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_o} \frac{\int_{\Omega} f(x,\omega) d\mu(\omega) - \int_{\Omega} f(x_o,\omega) d\mu(\omega)}{x-x_o}$.  But what do I now? Maybe:  $\lim_{x \rightarrow x_o} \int_{\Omega} \frac{  f(x,\omega) dµ(\omega) - f(x_o,\omega) d\mu(\omega)}{x-x_0}$. Is this right? Could I use now the dominated convergence theorem? Then I could use the fact that $f$ is differentiable? But I'm not sure.

Thank you for your reply.

Comment: Hint: try to apply the mean value theorem for fixed $\omega$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have $$\frac{F(x) - F(x_0)}{x-x_0} = \int_{\Omega} \frac{  f(x,\omega)  - f(x_0,\omega)}{x-x_0} d\mu(\omega)$$

Additionally you have that $$\left|\frac{f(x,\omega)  - f(x_0,\omega)}{x-x_0}\right| = \left|\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\ f(\xi,\omega)\right| \le g(\omega)$$ $\mu$-almost everywhere for a $\xi \in (x,x_0)$ hence you can use dominated convergence and you are done…

Comment: I understand your solution, but I have a few questions: First of all the dominated convergence theorem said: " $$ \int \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n dM = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int f_n dM $$  ; if $f_n$ measurable, | $f_n$| $\le$ $g$ , $g$ integrable.   I'm confused: What is my $f_n$ in this exercise? Where's my Limit? Sorry for my questions. Perhaps they are "obvious".

Comment: Let's answer the second question first: Your limit is $$\lim_{x\to x_0}$$ I just assumed this as obvious but it seems it wasn't although you already used it before. 
To answer your first question you should recap the definition of the symbol $$\lim_{x\to x_0}$$ to see that you do nothing else than working with a $$\lim_{n\to\infty}$$ and can interchange limit and integration.